# Fetch parent-id in a bidirectional hibernate mapping

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, rest

I have a spring rest application with two entities with a bidirectional relationshop (one-to-many, many to one). To overcome nested fetching issues, @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference has been used for a perent/child relationship between entities.

The entites look as this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Parent implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private List<Child> childList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<Child> getChildList() {
        return childList;
    }

    public void setChildListe(List<Child> childListe) {
            this.childList = childList;
        }

    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Child implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Integer id;
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID")
    @JsonBackReference
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


}
```

This works fine when fetching the Parent element, the childset is then fetched alongside and displayed as an json-array.

However, there is no reference to parent in the child element due to the usage of jsonbackreferance.

I would like to either get the parent object attached to the child-elemens in the json response,  or at least fetch the parent id, when requesting for a singlle child element through rest.

All feedback will be appriciated :)

Comment: i have too to solve this issue

Comment: This type of problem usually stems from an issue with your design. If there is no chance of refactoring maybe you can just add the parent ID explicitly to the child - rather than have an entire back reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by using custom serializer/deserializer

This is how I procedeed (please adapt it to your own code):

**ChildSerializer**

```
public class ChildSerializer extends StdSerializer<Child> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -265706839304575646L;
    public ChildSerializer(Class<Child> t) {
        super(t);
    }
    public ChildSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }
    @Override
    public void serialize(Child child, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp)
            throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {

        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeStringField("name", child.getName());
        jg.writeStringField("surname", child.getSurname());
        Parent parent = child.getParent();
        jg.writeObjectFieldStart("parent");
        jg.writeStringField("name", parent.getName());
        jg.writeStringField("surname", parent.getSurname());
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ChildSerializer.class)
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7902561110976676934L;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Parent parent;

    public Child(String name, String surname, Parent parent) {
        this(name, surname);
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public Child(String name, String surname) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public Child() {
        super();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((parent == null) ? 0 : parent.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Child other = (Child) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (parent == null) {
            if (other.parent != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!parent.equals(other.parent))
            return false;
        if (surname == null) {
            if (other.surname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Parent**

```
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5604725691780073247L;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private List<Child> childs;

    public Parent(String name, String surname) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public Parent(String name, String surname, List<Child> childs) {
        this(name, surname);

        this.childs = childs;
    }
    public Parent() {
        super();
        childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public void addChild( Child child )
    {
        if( !childs.contains(child) )
        {
            child.setParent(this);
            childs.add(child);
        }
    }
    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }
    public void setChilds(List<Child> childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((childs == null) ? 0 : childs.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Parent other = (Parent) obj;
        if (childs == null) {
            if (other.childs != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!childs.equals(other.childs))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (surname == null) {
            if (other.surname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

My test method:

```
@Test
public void testJson()
{
    try 
    {
        Parent p = new Parent(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            p.addChild(new Child(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        }
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        String childJson = om.writeValueAsString(p.getChilds().get(0));
        System.out.println(childJson);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The final output was:

```
{"name":"b86eab86-9858-4536-9c5c-d44d22810fc1","surname":"9a6249f0-58df-44e5-a1b9-31fbad6e9f49","parent":{"name":"74b0cd97-64a1-4547-ab22-4e4eedd0759b","surname":"a33c79f3-6f26-478b-9e24-7df96b3b1f68"}}
```

Sadly annotation are powerfull but not always they allow to you to obtain what you need and so you have to do it "by yourself"

I hope this can be usefull